# Cannot check if boolean exists Rails 5

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

So I'm having a bit of an issue with an if statement, I have the database structured like so

[image]

So I'm looking to check whether the boolean is true or false this is how I'm trying to do the statement currently

```
<% if @course_modules_users.where(complete: true).nil? %>
  <i class="fas fa-check text-green float-left mr-1"></i>
  <span class="text-xs mr-2">Completed</span>
<% else %>
  <%= link_to complete_course_module_path(course_module.id), method: :put do %>
    <i class="fas fa-check text-grey-darkest float-left mr-2"></i>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

But I'm just seeing this

[image]

**Edit #1**

I can do something like this

`<% if @course_modules_users.where(complete: true) %>`

But then both ticks go to complete

[image]

But as you can see in the database only one is true.

**Edit #2**

`course_modules_users`

model

```
class CourseModulesUser < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :course_module
  belongs_to :courses_user

  after_update :update_courses_user, if: :completed?

  def siblings
    self.class.where(courses_user_id: self.courses_user_id)
  end

  def completed!
    self.update_attributes(complete: true)
  end

  def completed?
    siblings.all?(&:complete?)
  end

  def update_courses_user
    self.courses_user.completed!
  end
end
```

CoursesController show method

```
def show
  course = Course.friendly.find(params[:id])
  @course_modules = course.course_modules.order(created_at: :asc)
  @course_modules_users = CourseModulesUser.all
end
```

Hopefully that helps.

**Edit #3**

show

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>
  <section class="pt-4 px-8">
    <section class="flex flex-wrap justify-between">
      <h3 class="font-normal text-grey-dark mb-4 py-2">
        <% if current_user.isAdmin? %>
          <%= @course.title %>
        <% else %>
          <%= @course.title %> Modules
        <% end %>
      </h3>
      <%= render 'layouts/dashboard/account' %>
    </section>
  </section>

  <section class="px-8">
    <% if Order.exists?(user_id: current_user.id, course_id: @course.id) %>
      <% @course_modules.each do |course_module| %>
        <section class="accordion-toggle">
          <section class="w-full sm:pr-4 pb-4">
            <section class="rounded shadow bg-grey-lighter border-b">
              <section class="flex justify-between px-6 p-4">
                <section class="flex items-center px-6 text-grey-darker">
                  <section class="font-bold text-base">
                    <%= course_module.title %>
                  </section>
                </section>

                <section class="flex items-center">
                  <% if user_signed_in? %>
                    <% if current_user.isAdmin? %>
                      <%= link_to "Edit", edit_course_module_path(course_module), class: "text-base text-grey-dark hover:text-darker px-4 py-2 border-2 border-grey leading-none no-underline hover:border-2 hover:border-grey-dark" %>
                    <% else %>
                      <% @course_modules_users.each do |cmu| %>
                        <% if cmu.complete == true %>
                          <i class="fas fa-check text-green float-left mr-1"></i>
                          <span class="text-xs mr-2">Completed</span>
                        <% else %>
                          <%= link_to complete_course_module_path(course_module.id), method: :put do %>
                            <i class="fas fa-check text-grey-darkest float-left mr-2"></i>
                          <% end %>
                        <% end %>
                      <% end %>
                      <i class="flex items-center fal fa-angle-up"></i>
                    <% end %>
                  <% end %>
                </section>
              </section>
            </section>

            <section class="accordion-items hidden">
              <% course_module.course_exercises.each do |exercise| %>
                <section class="w-full">
                  <section class="rounded shadow bg-grey-lighter border-b">
                    <section class="flex justify-between px-6 p-4">
                      <section class="flex items-center px-6 text-grey-darker">
                        <section class="font-bold text-base pl-4">
                          - <%= exercise.title %>
                        </section>
                      </section>

                      <section>
                        <% if user_signed_in? %>
                          <% if current_user.isAdmin? %>
                            <%= link_to "Edit", edit_course_exercise_path(exercise), class: "text-base text-grey-dark hover:text-darker px-4 py-2 border-2 border-grey leading-none no-underline hover:border-2 hover:border-grey-dark" %>
                          <% else %>
                            <%= link_to "View Exercise", exercise, class: "text-base text-grey-dark hover:text-darker px-4 py-2 border-2 border-grey leading-none no-underline hover:border-2 hover:border-grey-dark" %>
                          <% end %>
                        <% end %>
                      </section>
                    </section>
                  </section>
                </section>
              <% end %>
            </section>
          </section>
        </section>
      <% end %>
    <% else %>
      <h3>You have not bought this course!</h3>

      <%= form_with(url: '/payments/create') do |f| %>
        <%= render partial: "stripe_checkout_button" %>
        <%= hidden_field_tag(:course_id, @course.id) %>

        <%= f.submit "Buy this course", class: "bg-blue hover:bg-blue-dark text-white font-semibold py-3 px-4 border-2 rounded-sm border-blue-dark shadow outline-none" %>
      <% end %>
  <% end %>
  </section>
<% else %>
  <section class="flex h-64 hero-banner p-4">
    <section class="flex items-center mx-auto">
      <h2 class="uppercase">
        <%= @course.title %>
      </h2>
    </section>
  </section>

  <section class="pt-4 px-4">
    <section class="w-full">
      <section class="rounded overflow-hidden shadow">
        <section style="padding: 56.25% 0 0 0; position: relative;">
          <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/<%= @course.trailer %>" style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%;" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </section>
      </section>
    </section>

    <section class="flex flex-wrap -mx-4">
      <section class="w-full lg:w-3/4 p-4">
        <section class="bg-grey-lightest shadow text-grey-darker p-4">
          <h2 class="font-normal mb-4">Course description</h2>
          <p class="font-normal whitespace-pre-wrap"><%= @course.description %></p>
        </section>
      </section>
      <section class="w-full lg:w-1/4 p-4">
        <section class="bg-grey-lightest shadow text-grey-darker p-4 mb-4">
          <h3 class="font-normal mb-4">Course Price</h3>
          <p class="font-bold text-3xl text-green">£<%= @course.price %></p>
        </section>

        <%= link_to "Sign up to purchase", new_user_registration_path, class: "bg-blue hover:bg-blue-dark text-white font-semibold py-3 px-4 border-2 rounded-sm border-blue-dark shadow outline-none no-underline" %>

        <section class="bg-grey-lightest shadow text-grey-darker py-4 px-4 mt-4">
          <h3 class="font-normal mb-4">Course Modules</h3>
            <% @course_modules.each do |course_module| %>
              <section class="py-2 border-b-2 border-light modules">
                <%= course_module.title %>
              </section>
          <% end %>
        </section>
      </section>
    </section>
  </section>
<% end %>
```

Comment: What is `@course_modules_users`?

Comment: @Pavan I have `course_modules` being displayed here but `course_modules_users` is to keep track of the module and user who completes it. So I have course modules https://i.gyazo.com/05b18ceb3888e906bdc13b96a6e9a227.png and course modules users https://i.gyazo.com/dd4141eaadcec0cc2f84a871be4eddfe.png

Comment: I mean how you defined `@course_modules_users`? Update the question with code

Comment: See edit 2 @Pavan hopefully that's what your looking for

Comment: See edit #3 @Pavan I get this https://gyazo.com/190dedd89ee8be45a071f5f684016868

Answer (score 1):

`@course_modules_users.where(complete: true)` will return an **`Array`**.

`[]` and `nil` are different concepts. `[] != nil`; `[].nil? == false`.

In ruby, everything other than `nil` and `false` is considered "truthy". This means, for example, `[]` is a "truthy" value.

Putting this knowledge together explains everything you've seen above:

```
<% if @course_modules_users.where(complete: true).nil? %>
```

This will **never** happen, since the result of that query is not `nil`; it's a (possibly empty) array.

```
<% if @course_modules_users.where(complete: true) %>
```

This will **always** happen, since any `Array` (even an empty one) is "truthy" in ruby.

---

There are various ways you could have written this instead, such as:

```
<% if @course_modules_users.where(complete: true).empty? %>
```

Or:

```
<% if @course_modules_users.where(complete: true).none? %>
```

Comment: Stricly saying it returns `ActiveRecord::Collection`. But all other is true.

Comment: Yes, strictly speaking. I simplified slightly.

Comment: @TomLord I tried the examples you provided but I'm still seeing https://i.gyazo.com/b0254db19013526502461aab49f2d709.png

Comment: @B.J.B Oh... You've now added the information that `@course_modules_users = CourseModulesUser.all`. Surely that should be something like  `@course_modules_users = CourseModuleUser.where(course_module: @course_modules)` instead?

Comment: You're only interested in checking whether users for **those** modules are `complete`; yet your current code is check whether users for **any** modules are `complete`.

Comment: Ok so I've swapped the controller to `@course_modules_users = CourseModulesUser.where(course_module: @course_modules)` but are there any changes to the view needed?

Comment: I can do `@course_modules_users = CourseModulesUser.where(complete: true)` in the rails console and it shows it complete record if that helps?

Comment: Still not working my end @TomLord, do you have any other suggestions. I did try the loop that Pavan suggested but that just did this https://gyazo.com/190dedd89ee8be45a071f5f684016868

Comment: @B.J.B I'm not 100% clear what the code should be, because I don't really know what you're trying to achieve. You described the problem as *"I'm looking to check whether the boolean is true or false"*, which is very ambiguous. What is *"the boolean"*? Can we reduce all of this code to a **minimal** example? You should be able to fully describe this in about 3-5 lines of code, not 100+ lines.

Comment: Based on the information you have provided, the `@course_modules_users.each ...` should definitely go through both branches of the conditional, since one is `true` and the other is `false`. However, I don't think that code is actually doing the right behaviour since it's still based on `CourseModulesUser.all`; ignoring the current `course` being viewed.

Comment: @TomLord The complete in the database table in the boolean, every module has a tick and I just simply need to check that the module has been completed or not. I now have `@course_modules_users = CourseModulesUser.where(course_module: @course_modules)` in the CoursesController show method